# Grafico 3D usando THREE.js

Tags: javascript, 3d

Buenas amigos, necesito saber como hacer un grafico 3D (algun tipo de estructura o caja) que en su interior trace una linea de acuerdo a unos valores que se les pasaran. Adjunto imagen de lo que quiero hacer.

He intentado crear un cubo sin textura, donde solo se vea las lineas que lo denotan, transparente para comenzar, pero tengo un problema con las texturas, en el editor online pero no me deja ver como se gustaria el codigo de edicion.

[image: Producto del editor online]

Lo que trato de implementar:

[image: Lo que se intenta hacer]

Link(s):
EDITOR ONLINE:  threejs.org/editor/
PAGINA OFICIAL: threejs.org/

Comment: Hola @Jose. En el título mencionas a `three.js`. Tendrías muchísimas más chances de obtener una buena respuesta si das más detalles. ¿qué intentaste hasta ahora (por más que no funcione)? Encontrarás el enlace para [edit] debajo de pregunta

Comment: Gracias por el concejo @Mariano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero que nada: ¿Que versión de **Three.js** estás utilizando?.

Esta pregunta es debido a que en la **versión inferior a la 81** puedes utilizar el objeto **EdgeHelper** para hacer las aristas y para quitar la malla  que tienes en las caras del cubo en el **MeshBasicMaterial** tienes que pasarle el valor **wireframe: False**:

```
shape3D_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color:0x9E0000,
    wireframe: false,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: this.shapes_settings.opacity
});
```

Después de esto agregaremos el objeto EdgesHelper:

```
shape3D                             =   new THREE.Mesh(shape3D_geometry,    shape3D_material);

this.scene.add(shape3D);

//  Generamos las aristas
edges                               =   new THREE.EdgesHelper(shape3D, 0x808080);
edges.material.linewidth            =   3;

this.scene.add(edges);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**: Lo de la versión te lo comento porque este objeto **EdgeHelper** fue removida en la versión 81.

En la **versión 81 en adelante**, si no mal recuerdo podrías usar:

- **WireframeGeometry**

Puedes checar en la [documentación oficial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene) y puedes checar [este ejemplo](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html):